# Couldn't Install angular cli with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I'm using 8.9.2 version of node js and when I tried to install angular cli

with this command : `npm -g install @angular/cli`

It is displaying some npm errors

This is what I got on my cmd prompt screen :

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...-2.3.0.tgz"},"engines'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\haris_000\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-05T12_19_58_814Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.. How did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the command to install Angular is:
npm install -g @angular/cli